# I want to use Rsubread package but in which version

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to use Rsubread package but it keeps giving error. it says this package is in another version but I couldn't find which version it is.

I downloaded and tried old versions but still didn't work. what should I do?

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection to 'http://bioconductor.org/bioclite.R'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed. 
2: In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open URL 'http://bioconductor.org/bioclite.R': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection to 'http://bioconductor.org/bioclite.R'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed. 
2: In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open URL 'http://bioconductor.org/bioclite.R': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Comment: Please provide clear directions (show commands) that lead to the error.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of rstudio?

Comment: Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Gamze/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rsubread’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: yes. latest version